# How to get the Owner of the ContextMenu (from Silverlight 4 toolkit)?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, contextmenu, silverlight-toolkit, owner

When I use ContextMenu from Silverlight 4 Toolkit I want to get ContextMenu instance's Owner, but it's not available since in ContextMenu class Owner is an internal property. For example, I have a Rectangle put inside a Border. When I right-click a Rectangle (and a context menu appears) I need to change the Rectangle Border's thickness to indicate that the Rectangle is the current element of the parent Grid, for example. So I try to use ContextMenu.Loaded event where I get the ContextMenu (through the sender parameter), but I can't get the Owner of that ContextMenu (i.e. the Rectangle with its Border). And I need that Owner to make its Border thicker. Please help me find the way to do that.

Comment: Maybe you mean the PlacementTarget property.

Comment: to vorrtex: I can't find the PlacementTarget property among ContextMenu's members in Silverlight. Is it supposed to be there in Silverlight or is it just there in WPF?

Comment: @Dmitriyz I've confused Silverlight with WPF. But I know what to do: use reflection and read the private field _owner.

Comment: Reflection doesn't work. It seems that it is impossible to get owner.

Comment: I think also ContextMenu element handles MouseRightButtonDown event of the owner, so I can't even set needed border thickness in that event handler. If I define an event handler for the border it just never goes there. Are there any other ways to keep ContextMenu and still do what I need?

Comment: @Dmitryz You can add the x:Name attribute to the border and change the thickness of the border from an event handler of MenuItem.

Comment: Thank you. I wish there were other ways to do that.

Comment: I found it! As I create my rectangles and their context menus dynamically I can set each rectangle's border's DataContext property explicitly like this: myContextMenu.Context = myBorder; myContextMenu.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(myContextMenu_Loaded); myBorder.SetValue(ContextMenuService.ContextMenuProperty, myContextMenu); ... Then in myContextMenu_Loaded function I can see my rectangle's border like this: Border neededBorder = (sender as ContextMenu).DataContext as Border; ... Thank you, vorrtex, for participating in my search :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only soultion I found was to set ContextMenu's DataContext to the needed element from code behind. And then to address the element on which the context menu was opened throught that DataContext property.