# Silverlight DataGrid: Toolkit ContextMenu over entire Row

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, datagrid, contextmenu, silverlight-toolkit

I'm developing a Silverlight 4 application and want to achieve a seemingly easy task:
I have this DataGrid:

```
<sdk:DataGrid x:Name="dg" Grid.Row="1"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="800" ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResults}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
                    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn SortMemberPath="Name" Header="Name" CellTemplate="{StaticResource SearchGridNameFieldtemplate}">

                        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn SortMemberPath="samAccountName" Header="Kontoname" CellTemplate="{StaticResource SearchGridAccountNameFieldtemplate}">

                        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>

                        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" 
            Binding="{Binding Principal.Description}" />
                        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Container" 
            Binding="{Binding Principal.ContainerDN}" />

                    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                </sdk:DataGrid>
```

Now I am using a DataTemplate for the TemplateColumn which uses a toolkit Contextmenu like this

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DirectoryUserSearchItemViewModel"  >
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <controlsInputToolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                                            <controlsInputToolkit:ContextMenu>
                                                <controlsInputToolkit:MenuItem Header="Eigenschaften" Command="{Binding EditItem}" Visibility="{Binding User.DistinguishedName, Converter={StaticResource UserPermissionVisibilityConverter},ConverterParameter=1;8}" CommandParameter="{Binding User}">
                                                    <controlsInputToolkit:MenuItem.Icon>
                                                        <Rectangle Width="16" Height="16" Fill="{StaticResource MoveUpBrush}"/>
                                                    </controlsInputToolkit:MenuItem.Icon>
                                                </controlsInputToolkit:MenuItem>
                                                <controlsInputToolkit:MenuItem Header="User endgültig löschen" Command="{Binding HardDeleteAccount}" Visibility="{Binding HardDeleteCommandVisibility}" CommandParameter="{Binding User}">
                                                    <controlsInputToolkit:MenuItem.Icon>
                                                        <Rectangle Width="16" Height="16" Fill="{StaticResource MoveUpBrush}"/>
                                                    </controlsInputToolkit:MenuItem.Icon>
                                                </controlsInputToolkit:MenuItem>
                                                <controlsInputToolkit:MenuItem Header="Externe Anwendung ausführen" Command="{Binding ExecuteExternalApplication}" CommandParameter="{Binding User}">
                                                    <controlsInputToolkit:MenuItem.Icon>
                                                        <Rectangle Width="16" Height="16" Fill="{StaticResource MoveUpBrush}"/>
                                                    </controlsInputToolkit:MenuItem.Icon>
                                                </controlsInputToolkit:MenuItem>
                                            </controlsInputToolkit:ContextMenu>
                                        </controlsInputToolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Principal.Name}"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
```

Here's the fun part: Do I really have to copy paste the whole context menu datatemplate FOR EACH column in my grid if I want to be able to right click anywhere in a row and activate the context menu? Can't I set this for an entire row? Other posts on stackoverflow didnt seem to give an answer to this specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As recomended in post https://stackoverflow.com/a/8795056/451495
You can use following:

```
public partial class Page1 : UserControl
{
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += OnLoaded;
        Grid1.LoadingRow += Grid1OnLoadingRow;
    }

    private void Grid1OnLoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        var contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        var deleteMenuItem = new System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem { Header = "text" };
        contextMenu.Items.Add(deleteMenuItem);
        ContextMenuService.SetContextMenu(e.Row, contextMenu);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a word of caution, if you do this, you would probably want to detach the context menu in "UnloadingRow" in order to prevent memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

You might try adding column names and then calling ContextMenuService.SetContextMenu to add the ContextMenu to the other columns.

The next challenge is determining which column was right-clicked.

Related posts:
[How to get the Owner of the ContextMenu (from Silverlight 4 toolkit)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361075/how-to-get-the-owner-of-the-contextmenu-from-silverlight-4-toolkit)
[Silverlight Toolkit ContextMenu: Which control was right-clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909885/silverlight-toolkit-contextmenu-which-control-was-right-clicked)